Configuring ISC DHCP-server on Debian
I am trying install and configure ISC DHCP-server on debian 12 and . But I keep getting the following errors in syslog.
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]: No subnet declaration for enp2s0 (no IPv4 addresses).
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]: ** Ignoring requests on enp2s0.  If this is not what
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]:    to which interface enp2s0 is attached. **
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]: 
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]: 
Jul 26 13:42:38 3ecc1b69 dhcpd[774]: Not configured to listen on any interface

Below are the cofiguration files
dhcpd.conf
  subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
        option routers 192.168.1.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    }

interfaces
    source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
    
  


  allow-hotplug enp2s0
    iface enp2s0 static
        address 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACESv4="enp2s0"
INTERFACESv6="enp2s0"

Attempting to start the server produces this output
    Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service" and "journalctl -xeu isc-dhcp-server.service" for details.


systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service provides this output

isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
         Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server; generated)
         Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-07-26 16:11:23 EEST; 57s ago
           Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
        Process: 1290 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
            CPU: 39ms
    
    Jul 26 16:11:21 3ecc1b69 systemd[1]: Starting isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server...
    Jul 26 16:11:21 3ecc1b69 isc-dhcp-server[1290]: Launching IPv4 server only.
    Jul 26 16:11:23 3ecc1b69 isc-dhcp-server[1290]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
    Jul 26 16:11:23 3ecc1b69 isc-dhcp-server[1290]:  failed!
    Jul 26 16:11:23 3ecc1b69 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Jul 26 16:11:23 3ecc1b69 systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Jul 26 16:11:23 3ecc1b69 systemd[1]: Failed to start isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server.


What does the configuration of enp2s0 look like (show the output of ip addr show enp2s0)? This helps confirm that your interfaces configuration is applying correctly.

There was an error in the interfaces defintion. Fixing that fixed my issue.
